# coulmn match doesnt not match value at row 1 in php and mysql

Tags: php

Hi everyone im having an html form whereby the admin users are able to enter in new route and is storing into the database, but after filling all fields and clicking on SUBMIT it says Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
and im not sure what causes the problem here is my code:

```
<?php 
include_once('includes/connect.php');
$conn = new DataConnection;
if (! isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "undefined action";
}

@$code_name = htmlentities($_POST['code_name']);
@$depart_from = htmlentities($_POST['depart_from']);
@$arrive_to = htmlentities($_POST['arrive_to']);
@$report_time = htmlentities($_POST['report_time']);
@$depart_time = htmlentities($_POST['depart_time']);
@$depart_date = htmlentities($_POST['depart_date']);
@$price = htmlentities($_POST['price']);
@$category = htmlentities($_POST['category']);
$query = $conn->query("INSERT INTO buses_list VALUES(null,$code_name',  '$depart_from', '$arrive_to', '$report_time', '$depart_time', '$depart_date', '$price', '$category')") or die($conn->error);

if ($query){
$_SESSION['message'] = "A new bus has been added";
header("Location: bus.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: The column counts in the database is not equal to the variable counts null,$code_name',  '$depart_from', '$arrive_to', '$report_time', '$depart_time', '$depart_date', '$price', '$category'

Comment: but null is auto increment in the database

Comment: how can i do it? i have removed null but still comes in the error...

Comment: Change the query like this and try: $query = $conn->query("INSERT INTO buses_list (column1, column2, etc.....) VALUES(null,$code_name',  '$depart_from', '$arrive_to', '$report_time', '$depart_time', '$depart_date', '$price', '$category')") or die($conn->error);

Comment: and what about the null part--> the null part is id should i write it too since it is auto increment..

Comment: thank you it worked mate :) x